# How to read data from finger print reader and convert into image file in java

Tags: java, fingerprint

i have to read data from finger print reader and convert into image file. I am using Digital Persona 's device U and U 4500 with Platinum SDK . I am  new biometric field. Till now I am only able to detect the device means whether it is connected to system or not.Please guide me what should i do to accomplish this task

i have used this Code(only to check whether device  is working )

```
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPGlobal;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.DPFPSample;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.DPFPCapture; 
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPDataEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPDataListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPErrorEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPErrorListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPReaderStatusAdapter; 
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPReaderStatusEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPReaderStatusListener;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPSensorEvent;
import com.digitalpersona.onetouch.capture.event.DPFPSensorListener;


public class Demo {
public static void main(String args[]){
//byte[] a=null;
DPFPCapture capture=DPFPGlobal.getCaptureFactory().createCapture();
capture.addReaderStatusListener(new DPFPReaderStatusListener() {

    @Override
    public void readerDisconnected(DPFPReaderStatusEvent arg0) {
         //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("I m Dis-connected");

    }

    @Override
    public void readerConnected(DPFPReaderStatusEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("I m connected");
    }
});
capture.addSensorListener(new DPFPSensorListener() {

    @Override
    public void imageAcquired(DPFPSensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("acquired");
    }

    @Override
    public void fingerTouched(DPFPSensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("s");
    }

    @Override
    public void fingerGone(DPFPSensorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.print("gone");
    }
});
capture.startCapture();
capture.addDataListener(new DPFPDataListener() {

    @Override
    public void dataAcquired(DPFPDataEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DPFPSample sample=DPFPGlobal.getSampleFactory().createSample();
        sample=arg0.getSample();    
        byte a[]=sample.serialize();
        for(byte i:a){
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
});
capture.addErrorListener(new DPFPErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(DPFPErrorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("error");
    }

    @Override
    public void errorOccured(DPFPErrorEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("error");

    }
});

}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question in it's current form is very broad. Please tell us what you have tried, what the results were, and where you got stuck.

Comment: Have you tried anything ? could you provide some code example ?

Comment: **How** is it connected? TCP/IP? RS/232? Carrier Pidgeon? ;)

Comment: Mr. Fildor r you asking about connectivity of device ,The device is connected to my system by USB. I have installed all the driver for this .

Comment: According to the documentation there is sample code in the installation directory. Have you looked at this?

Comment: There is no sample code in the folder . The installed folder only contains jar files dpfpenrollment,dpfpverification,dpotapi,dpotjni. Sample code folder contains example of VB,C++,C# noothing about java. The verson of Platinum SDK is 3.1

Answer (score 1):

I am also currently working on a Digital Persona Finger Print Reader, I actually had the same Problem but now i have overcome it,
I think the code to add the Listeners should be in the init() method and also start the init method in the constructor of the class
The main method should only instantiate the Class.